# Cannot convert file to .mp4 using phpvideotoolkit

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am using the phpvideotoolkit http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html to convert video to .mp4 formats. As I run this file as an example

> http://localhost/phpvideotoolkit-v2-master/examples/convert-to-flv.php

I got the following errors, please help explain how I could use phpvideotoolkit to convert any video to .mp4. Although the following file is present in C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 but the error message is still shown.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ERROR---------
    [1] => exception
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => InvalidArgumentException Object
                (
                    [message:protected] => The file "C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" cannot be found in \PHPVideoToolkit\Media::__construct.
                    [string:Exception:private] => 
                    [code:protected] => 0
                    [file:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                    [line:protected] => 254
                    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                                    [line] => 75
                                    [function] => setMediaPath
                                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                                    [type] => ->
                                    [args] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Video.php
                                    [line] => 35
                                    [function] => __construct
                                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                                    [type] => ->
                                    [args] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                                            [1] => 
                                            [2] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-flv.php
                                    [line] => 9
                                    [function] => __construct
                                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Video
                                    [type] => ->
                                    [args] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [previous:Exception:private] => 
                    [xdebug_message] => <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> InvalidArgumentException: The file "C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" cannot be found in \PHPVideoToolkit\Media::__construct. in C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php on line <i>254</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0290</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>260072</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-flv.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\convert-to-flv.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.3640</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1089856</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Video->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-flv.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\convert-to-flv.php<b>:</b>9</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.3640</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1090336</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Video.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Video.php<b>:</b>35</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.4220</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1100088</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->setMediaPath(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Media.php<b>:</b>75</td></tr>

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [function] => __errorHandler
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => InvalidArgumentException Object
                                (
                                    [message:protected] => The file "C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" cannot be found in \PHPVideoToolkit\Media::__construct.
                                    [string:Exception:private] => 
                                    [code:protected] => 0
                                    [file:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                                    [line:protected] => 254
                                    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                                                    [line] => 75
                                                    [function] => setMediaPath
                                                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                                                    [type] => ->
                                                    [args] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Video.php
                                                    [line] => 35
                                                    [function] => __construct
                                                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                                                    [type] => ->
                                                    [args] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                                                            [1] => 
                                                            [2] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-flv.php
                                                    [line] => 9
                                                    [function] => __construct
                                                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Video
                                                    [type] => ->
                                                    [args] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [previous:Exception:private] => 
                                    [xdebug_message] => <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> InvalidArgumentException: The file "C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" cannot be found in \PHPVideoToolkit\Media::__construct. in C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php on line <i>254</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0290</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>260072</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-flv.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\convert-to-flv.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.3640</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1089856</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Video->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-flv.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\convert-to-flv.php<b>:</b>9</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.3640</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1090336</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Video.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Video.php<b>:</b>35</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.4220</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1100088</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->setMediaPath(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Media.php<b>:</b>75</td></tr>

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the difference between this question and your other one, [How to convert any video type to .mp4 using phpvideotoolkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129302/how-to-convert-any-video-type-to-mp4-using-phpvideotoolkit)?

Comment: LordNeckbeard- Both question errors are different I have resolved the above error but got stuck  in another one. The error which is there can be found on this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129302/how-to-convert-any-video-type-to-mp4-using-phpvideotoolkit. Please help to sort out my issue if u can.