# How to convert any video type to .mp4 using phpvideotoolkit

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am following this http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html link to convert any video type to .mp4 i tried to run various example files but they are throwing error message. I can't get how to convert the file using phpvideotoolkit.

If i run the following file http://localhost/phpvideotoolkit-v2-master/examples/convert-to-multiple-outputs.php i get this error.

```
An error was encountered with FFmpeg when attempting to read the formats that FFmpeg supports. FFmpeg reported: The system cannot find the path specified.


 PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegProcessException Object
(
    [process:protected] => PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegProcess Object
        (
            [_exec:protected] => PHPVideoToolkit\ExecBuffer Object
                (
                    [_failure_tracking:protected] => 1
                    [_blocking:protected] => 1
                    [_output:protected] => 
                    [_temp_directory:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\tmp
                    [_executed_command:protected] => ((/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg "-formats" && echo ^<c-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e^>) || echo ^<f-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e^> ^<c-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e^> ^<e-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e^>) 2>&1 > "C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\tmp\php5359.tmp" 2>&1 &
                    [_command:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg "-formats"
                    [_buffer:protected] => The system cannot find the path specified.
<f-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e> <c-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e> <e-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e>

                    [_error_code:protected] => 0
                    [_running:protected] => 
                    [_start_time:protected] => 1449479003.9261
                    [_end_time:protected] => 1449479003.9841
                    [_callback_period_interval:protected] => 1
                    [_boundary:protected] => 749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e
                    [_failure_boundary:protected] => <f-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e>
                    [_completion_boundary:protected] => <c-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e>
                    [_error_code_boundary:protected] => <e-749429-56654b5be19a9-f741fa350232252bd14d9abb334a7e6e>
                    [_php_exec_infinite_timelimit:protected] => 1
                    [_tmp_files:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\tmp\php5359.tmp
                        )

                    [_gc_temp_files:protected] => 1
                    [_completion_callbacks:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [_pre_input_commands:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_input:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_output_index:protected] => 0
            [_post_input_commands:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [-formats] => 
                        )

                )

            [_output:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_post_output_commands:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_progress_handler:protected] => 
            [_combined:protected] => 1
            [_program_path:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
            [_arguments:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -formats
                )

            [_config] => PHPVideoToolkit\Config Object
                (
                    [_ffmpeg:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
                    [_ffprobe:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffprobe
                    [_yamdi:protected] => /opt/local/bin/yamdi
                    [_qtfaststart:protected] => /opt/local/bin/qt-faststart
                    [_temp_directory:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\tmp
                    [_gif_transcoder:protected] => php
                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_dither:protected] => 
                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_dither_order:protected] => o8x8,8
                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_coalesce:protected] => 
                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_map:protected] => 
                    [_gifsicle:protected] => /opt/local/bin/gifsicle
                    [_convert:protected] => /opt/local/bin/convert
                    [_php_exec_infinite_timelimit:protected] => 1
                    [_force_enable_qtfaststart:protected] => 
                    [_force_enable_flv_meta:protected] => 1
                    [_cache_driver:protected] => InTempDirectory
                    [_set_default_output_format:protected] => 1
                )

        )

    [exec:protected] => 
    [message:protected] => An error was encountered with FFmpeg when attempting to read the formats that FFmpeg supports. FFmpeg reported: The system cannot find the path specified.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Parser.php
    [line:protected] => 99
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser.php
                    [line] => 51
                    [function] => getRawFormatData
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Parser
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser.php
                    [line] => 78
                    [function] => _getParser
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Format.php
                    [line] => 122
                    [function] => __call
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => getCommands
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Format.php
                    [line] => 122
                    [function] => getCommands
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\AudioFormat.php
                    [line] => 52
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Format
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => input
                            [1] => PHPVideoToolkit\Config Object
                                (
                                    [_ffmpeg:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
                                    [_ffprobe:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffprobe
                                    [_yamdi:protected] => /opt/local/bin/yamdi
                                    [_qtfaststart:protected] => /opt/local/bin/qt-faststart
                                    [_temp_directory:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\tmp
                                    [_gif_transcoder:protected] => php
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_dither:protected] => 
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_dither_order:protected] => o8x8,8
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_coalesce:protected] => 
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_map:protected] => 
                                    [_gifsicle:protected] => /opt/local/bin/gifsicle
                                    [_convert:protected] => /opt/local/bin/convert
                                    [_php_exec_infinite_timelimit:protected] => 1
                                    [_force_enable_qtfaststart:protected] => 
                                    [_force_enable_flv_meta:protected] => 1
                                    [_cache_driver:protected] => InTempDirectory
                                    [_set_default_output_format:protected] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\VideoFormat.php
                    [line] => 61
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\AudioFormat
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => input
                            [1] => PHPVideoToolkit\Config Object
                                (
                                    [_ffmpeg:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
                                    [_ffprobe:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffprobe
                                    [_yamdi:protected] => /opt/local/bin/yamdi
                                    [_qtfaststart:protected] => /opt/local/bin/qt-faststart
                                    [_temp_directory:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\tmp
                                    [_gif_transcoder:protected] => php
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_dither:protected] => 
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_dither_order:protected] => o8x8,8
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_coalesce:protected] => 
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_map:protected] => 
                                    [_gifsicle:protected] => /opt/local/bin/gifsicle
                                    [_convert:protected] => /opt/local/bin/convert
                                    [_php_exec_infinite_timelimit:protected] => 1
                                    [_force_enable_qtfaststart:protected] => 
                                    [_force_enable_flv_meta:protected] => 1
                                    [_cache_driver:protected] => InTempDirectory
                                    [_set_default_output_format:protected] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                    [line] => 226
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\VideoFormat
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => input
                            [1] => PHPVideoToolkit\Config Object
                                (
                                    [_ffmpeg:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg
                                    [_ffprobe:protected] => /opt/local/bin/ffprobe
                                    [_yamdi:protected] => /opt/local/bin/yamdi
                                    [_qtfaststart:protected] => /opt/local/bin/qt-faststart
                                    [_temp_directory:protected] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\tmp
                                    [_gif_transcoder:protected] => php
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_dither:protected] => 
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_dither_order:protected] => o8x8,8
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_coalesce:protected] => 
                                    [_gif_transcoder_convert_use_map:protected] => 
                                    [_gifsicle:protected] => /opt/local/bin/gifsicle
                                    [_convert:protected] => /opt/local/bin/convert
                                    [_php_exec_infinite_timelimit:protected] => 1
                                    [_force_enable_qtfaststart:protected] => 
                                    [_force_enable_flv_meta:protected] => 1
                                    [_cache_driver:protected] => InTempDirectory
                                    [_set_default_output_format:protected] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                    [line] => 188
                    [function] => _getDefaultFormat
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => input
                            [1] => VideoFormat
                            [2] => 
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                    [line] => 150
                    [function] => getDefaultFormat
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => input
                            [1] => mp4
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php
                    [line] => 78
                    [function] => setInputFormat
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Video.php
                    [line] => 35
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Media
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 
                        )

                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-3gp.php
                    [line] => 9
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => PHPVideoToolkit\Video
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples/media/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [xdebug_message] => <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegProcessException: An error was encountered with FFmpeg when attempting to read the formats that FFmpeg supports. FFmpeg reported: The system cannot find the path specified. in C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Parser.php on line <i>99</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>259704</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-3gp.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\convert-to-3gp.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0420</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1089432</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Video->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\examples\convert-to-3gp.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\convert-to-3gp.php<b>:</b>9</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0420</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1089912</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Video.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Video.php<b>:</b>35</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0510</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1099872</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->setInputFormat(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Media.php<b>:</b>78</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>5</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0670</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1385064</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->getDefaultFormat(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Media.php<b>:</b>150</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>6</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0670</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1385368</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Media->_getDefaultFormat(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Media.php<b>:</b>188</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>7</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0780</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1692632</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\VideoFormat->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Media.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Media.php<b>:</b>226</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>8</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0780</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1692864</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\AudioFormat->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\VideoFormat.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\VideoFormat.php<b>:</b>61</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>9</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0780</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1693192</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Format->__construct(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\AudioFormat.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\AudioFormat.php<b>:</b>52</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>10</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0780</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1694784</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser.getCommands' target='_new'>getCommands</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Format.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Format.php<b>:</b>122</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>11</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0780</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1695080</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser->__call(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Format.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Format.php<b>:</b>122</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>12</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0780</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1695248</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser->_getParser(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\FfmpegParser.php<b>:</b>78</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>13</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0810</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>1696512</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PHPVideoToolkit\Parser->getRawFormatData(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\phpvideotoolkit-v2-master\src\PHPVideoToolkit\FfmpegParser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\FfmpegParser.php<b>:</b>51</td></tr>

)
```

Comment: Can you tell us the text of the error messages and where they occur?

Comment: Sascha- I have updated my question

Comment: Have you checked that the file exists in the location mentioned in the error message? If so, do you have read access to it?

Comment: Yes it is present and read access is given to it.

Comment: I have checked the documentation also but it did'nt give a clear method of running the following example.

Comment: The path has mixed slashes and backslashes. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97174/discussion-between-user3653474-and-sascha).